# Creating image from two other images using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am having a slight problem, I need to be able to create image file from two other images, and I have to able to place other image over the other one.
Example:

Blue_box.png:

[image: Blue box]

Yellow_box.png:

[image: Yellow box]

And I have to let javascript create a new image file that would look something like this:

Final_box.png:

[image]

And I have to be able to place the yellow box using cords

Comment: Tried using `canvas` element ?

Comment: There are 5 different questions with at least 10 answers here. Start by explaining what you've tried so far